# Angular js directive in module not working correctly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing, angularjs-module

I have one module call "menuLeft", when  module  he initiate ,not loading  correctly my directive, but if run my function en el method "run" correctly.
I dont know why is this.
This is my code

```
(function () {

 angular.module('menuLeft', []);

angular.module('menuLeft')
    .run(htmlMenuDirectivaGrupo)
    .directive('ctrlMenuDirectivaGrupo', ctrlMenuDirectivaGrupo);


//MY MENU DIRECTIVE (THIS NOT LOAD)
//MENU GRUPO
/**
 * @ngInject
 */
function ctrlMenuDirectivaGrupo($timeout) {
    alert('hello ctrlmenu');

    return {
        scope: {
            section: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'partials/menuToogle.tmpl.html',
        link: function ($scope, $element) {
            var controller = $element.parent().controller();

            $scope.isOpen = function () {
                return controller.isOpen($scope.section);
            };
            $scope.toggle = function () {
                controller.toggleOpen($scope.section);
            };
        }
    };


}



 //MY TEMPLATE FOR DIRECTIVE (THIS IF LOAD)
/**
 * @ngInject
 */
function htmlMenuDirectivaGrupo($templateCache) {
alert('hello htmlmenu');
    $templateCache.put('partials/menuToogle.tmpl.html',
        '<md-button class="md-button-toggle"\n' +
        '  ng-click="toggle()"\n' +
        '  aria-controls="docs-menu-{{section.name | nospace}}"\n' +
        '  flex layout="row"\n' +
        '  aria-expanded="{{isOpen()}}">\n' +
        '  {{section.name}}\n' +
        '  <span aria-hidden="true" class=" pull-right fa fa-chevron-down md-toggle-icon"\n' +
        '  ng-class="{\'toggled\' : isOpen()}"></span>\n' +
        '</md-button>\n' +
        '<ul ng-show="isOpen()" id="docs-menu-{{section.name | nospace}}" class="menu-toggle-list">\n' +
        '  <li ng-repeat="page in section.pages">\n' +
        '    <menu-link section="page"></menu-link>\n' +
        '  </li>\n' +
        '</ul>\n' +
        '');


}

})();
```

Why not load two functions?, there are bad code or declarations?
thanks.

Comment: try like this `angular.module('menuLeft', []).run(htmlMenuDirectivaGrupo)
    .directive('ctrlMenuDirectivaGrupo', ctrlMenuDirectivaGrupo);`

Comment: In this module I do several angular.module('menuLeft').run().directives();besides, this is the same as calling once loaded.

Comment: Yes, you can follow links like this, https://toddmotto.com/opinionated-angular-js-styleguide-for-teams/

Comment: Create plunker or fiddle to optimize code.

Comment: The code is quite ligth .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is , what my directive nor declaring correctly in .html
This is the way we should call it to function properly.

DIRECTIVES

```
  (function () {

 angular.module('menuLeft', []);

angular.module('menuLeft')
    .run(htmlMenuDirectivaGrupo)
    .directive('menuGrupo', ctrlMenuDirectivaGrupo);


//MY MENU DIRECTIVE (THIS NOT LOAD)
//MENU GRUPO
/**
 * @ngInject
 */
function ctrlMenuDirectivaGrupo($timeout) {
    alert('hello ctrlmenu');

    return {
        scope: {
            section: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'partials/menuToogle.tmpl.html',
        link: function ($scope, $element) {
            var controller = $element.parent().controller();

            $scope.isOpen = function () {
                return controller.isOpen($scope.section);
            };
            $scope.toggle = function () {
                controller.toggleOpen($scope.section);
            };
        }
    };


}



 //MY TEMPLATE FOR DIRECTIVE (THIS IF LOAD)
/**
 * @ngInject
 */
function htmlMenuDirectivaGrupo($templateCache) {
alert('hello htmlmenu');
    $templateCache.put('partials/menuToogle.tmpl.html',
        '<md-button class="md-button-toggle"\n' +
        '  ng-click="toggle()"\n' +
        '  aria-controls="docs-menu-{{section.name | nospace}}"\n' +
        '  flex layout="row"\n' +
        '  aria-expanded="{{isOpen()}}">\n' +
        '  {{section.name}}\n' +
        '  <span aria-hidden="true" class=" pull-right fa fa-chevron-down md-toggle-icon"\n' +
        '  ng-class="{\'toggled\' : isOpen()}"></span>\n' +
        '</md-button>\n' +
        '<ul ng-show="isOpen()" id="docs-menu-{{section.name | nospace}}" class="menu-toggle-list">\n' +
        '  <li ng-repeat="page in section.pages">\n' +
        '    <menu-link section="page"></menu-link>\n' +
        '  </li>\n' +
        '</ul>\n' +
        '');


}

})();
```

HTML

```
  <menu-grupo></menu-grupo>
```

I recommend reading  https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

> Use something like this . .

```
   return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {            
        section: '='
    },
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope){..}],
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {..},
    template:   '<div class="bootsrtap">'+
                    '<input type="text" ng-model="searchParam"  placeholder="{{ attrs.placeholder }}"'+
                        'class="{{ attrs.inputclass }}"'+
                        'id="{{ attrs.inputid }}"'+
                         'ng-required="{{ autocompleteRequired }}" />'+
                '</div> '
};
```

Comment: this is also the same as what I show. my problem that the directive is not charged